# CodeBlocks not refreshing my program after modifying code

Tags: c, codeblocks

Thanks.

So when I write some code into codeblocks using c language and run it, granted the code is error free, it runs fine. Subsequent modifying and running of the code only produces the results of the first time I ran the code unless I delete the executable and object files. In other words it is not updating to the code that I modify. I am running the latest version of CodeBlocks. Is this a setting I need to change?

Update:

After reading the answers and comments below, I was able to correct the problem. As many suggested I indeed needed to click "build and run". I know it's such a basic question but I'm new to programming so thanks for your help. The confusion came when I would first click to "run" a code it would automatically ask me if I wanted to build it first. So I just thought every time I clicked "run" it would automatically build it first.

Comment: I don't have the IDE installed, but it sounds like when you hit the run button it doesn't recompile the code by default. It could be that it only recompiles if it sees that the executable and object files are missing. You should build it first if that's the case

Comment: Most IDEs have a combined “Build and Run” button, but I don’t know if Code::Blocks does.

Comment: Assuming you have a "project" created and you are using `Ctrl + F9` ***Build*** or `F9` ***Build & Run***, then the executable will be updated. Now it may be in the `Debug` directory, or `Release` directory depending on your settings. Advice -- for small projects, always use the command line compiler, otherwise you will never have the feel for compiler options. IDE's like codeblocks, can become a crutch as much as they are a tool if you don't understand the basics.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: It would be helpful if you will share some screenshots showing us how you are running/compiling the code from CodeBlocks.

Answer (score 1):

In Codeblocks, there should be a "Build and Run" button to fix your problem assuming that you were only pressing "run" before you read this

[Build and Run Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouzaP.png)